# Include file contents into LaTeX on the same line

Tags: luatex, verbatim, external-files

I'm trying to generate a pdf file where a certain part contains user input. I want it to be put on the same line, with the same font, and without special characters messing up the parsing. I thought I could get this by putting the user input into a file and reading it with the `\verbatiminput` command from the `verbatim` package, but I don't quite get the result I want.

`name.txt` has this contents:

```
Bobby {[(*&%#@!_\':>?, ,.;;'\][ Tables
```

This is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{}
\makeatother

For \verbatiminput{name.txt}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Not quite what I want, the file contents is put on a separate line]

The contents of `name.txt` is put on a separate line and indented to the left.

But this is what I really want:

[image: The result I want, file contents is put on the same line]

It's as if I typed the contents of `name.txt` with all the proper escaping on the same line.

Is there a package that can do this? Or a way to configure `verbatim`? I tried looking at its code, but could only figure out how to keep the font the same, not how to keep it in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare you own verbatim environment `\setverb`:

```
\def\setverb{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}\dospecials }
\def\verbinput#1{\bgroup \setverb \input{#1}\unskip\egroup}

For \verbinput{name.txt}, next text.

\bye
```

An you must to use ASCII encoded font, no default cmr10 (i is not ASCII encoded unfortunately).

Comment: Thank you! I think I like this solution the best, but will wait a bit before accepting in case someone else comes up with another idea. I'm not sure what you mean with the last sentence. Your solution seems to work well for the character `i` and special characters like `ö`, I'm using `lualatex`

Answer (score 4):

`\verbatiminput` is implemented using a `\trivlist` (like an equation) and consists of multiple lines of text.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{}
\makeatother

\hrule
\noindent For \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\verbatiminput{name.txt}}
\hrule

\end{document}
```